# How to get a number of rows in SQLITE database using JS, Node.JS and Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

I have run into the issue regarding using Sequelize and Sqlite for creating a database for my Discord bot.

My table consists of rows with columns: "username", "description", "key", "name" and "displayname". 
I want to get a number of rows, e.g. a number of users in my table.

I did not find any particular function for getting a number of rows of particular table, so I decided to use arrays instead, where I push every 'displayname' attribute. 
This did not take me anywhere and instead of the number of array elements when using array.length(), the code outputs 'object undefined' value.

Here's the code:

```js
else if (cmd === `${prefix}alist`) {
  // equivalent to: SELECT name FROM tags;
  const notdone = [];
  const done = [];
  var s;
  const tagList = await Tags.findAll({
    attributes: ['displayname']
  });
  const tagListDone = await TagsDone.findAll({
    attributes: ['displaynamedone']
  });
  notdone.push(tagList.map(t => t.displayname));
  done.push(tagListDone.map(t => t.displaynamedone));
  const notdonestring = notdone.join(' ');
  const donestring = done.join(' ');
  s = Math.round(done.length / (notdone.length + done.length));
  message.reply(toString(done.length) + ' ' + toString(notdone.length));
  return message.channel.send(`Список заданий: \n` + notdonestring + `\n \nСписок выполненных: \n` + donestring + '\n \nНаш прогресс: ' + toString(s) + '%');
}
```

Here's the code output:
[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKYnx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to get a number of rows just use `count` instead of `findAll`:

```
 const tagCount = await Tags.count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, this does not work as intended. I'm still getting [object undefined] instead of the number of rows. I even made a raw check on this issue, so it is clearly something wrong with this function.
            p.s. Instead of the bulk code above I decided to leave just `const s1 = await Tags.count();
            message.reply(toString(s1));` but it still does not work

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the `message.reply` line and look at `s1` manually?

Comment: Thank you for the help, Anatoly! Using debugging actually helped to find the issue! Cheers!